# Dereferencing a pointer at runtime in c

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am trying to dereferencing a pointer, according to the data-type passed to the function, just to learn.

code 1: First Try. Oviously it didn't work.

```
typedef enum
{
    bits_8,
    bits_16,
    bits_32
}bits_width;


inline int32_t write_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer_x_bits( void* data_address, uint32_t size, bits_width data_type )
{       
    switch( data_type )
    {
        case bits_8:
            spi1_change_mode_8_bits();
            uint8_t* dt = (uint8_t*)data_address; 
        break;

        case bits_16:
            spi1_change_mode_16_bits();
            uint16_t* dt = (uint16_t*)data_address;   
        break;

        case bits_32:            
            spi1_change_mode_32_bits();
            uint32_t* dt = (uint32_t*)data_address;    
        break;
        
        default:
            return -1;
        break;
    }
        
    for( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {       
        while( SPI1STATbits.SPITBF );    
        SPI1BUF = *dt++;  // Write the data out to the SPI1 peripheral. *dt++ = dt[i].
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

code 2: Looks OK(compile). Not tested in hardware.

```
typedef enum
{
    bits_8,
    bits_16,
    bits_32
}bits_width;


inline int32_t write_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer_x_bits( uint8_t* data_address, uint32_t size, bits_width data_type )
{       
    uint32_t x;
    
    switch( data_type )
    {
        case bits_8:
            spi1_change_mode_8_bits();
            x = 1; 
        break;

        case bits_16:
            spi1_change_mode_16_bits();
            x = 2;   
        break;

        case bits_32:            
            //spi1_change_mode_32_bits();
            x = 4;    
        break;
        
        default:
            return -1;
        break;
    }
        
    for( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {       
        while( SPI1STATbits.SPITBF );    
        SPI1BUF = *( data_address + (i*x) );  // Write the data out to the SPI1 peripheral.
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

code 3: I did not want to write the for loop 3 times(one for each data type).

```
typedef enum
{
    bits_8,
    bits_16,
    bits_32
}bits_width;


inline int32_t write_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer_x_bits( void* data_address, uint32_t size, bits_width data_type )
{       
    switch( data_type )
    {
        case bits_8:
            spi1_change_mode_8_bits();
            uint8_t* dt = (uint8_t*)data_address; 

            for( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
            {       
                while( SPI1STATbits.SPITBF );    
                SPI1BUF = *dt++;  // Write the data out to the SPI1 peripheral. *dt++ = dt[i].
            }

        break;

        case bits_16:
            spi1_change_mode_16_bits();
            uint16_t* dt = (uint16_t*)data_address;   

            for( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
            {       
                while( SPI1STATbits.SPITBF );    
                SPI1BUF = *dt++;  // Write the data out to the SPI1 peripheral. *dt++ = dt[i].
            }

        break;

        case bits_32:            
            spi1_change_mode_32_bits();
            uint32_t* dt = (uint32_t*)data_address;    

            for( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
            {       
                while( SPI1STATbits.SPITBF );    
                SPI1BUF = *dt++;  // Write the data out to the SPI1 peripheral. *dt++ = dt[i].
            }
        break;
        
        default:
            return -1;
        break;
    }

    return 0;        
}
```

How to make code 1 work ?

Or is there a better solution ?

Thank`s.

Comment: Never describe a problem as “it didn’t work”. Always state the observed behavior, whether that is a compiler message, a crash, or undesired output, and describe the desired behavior (preferably give an example), and describe the different. Edit the question to provide a [mre] for “code 1”, including code that other people can compile without any change or additions to reproduce the problem you are having. If the problem is the code does not compile, that is okay, just provide enough code so other people can exactly reproduce the compilation error. Otherwise, provide a `main` routine.

Comment: `while( SPI1STATbits.SPITBF );`  will run forever. It's an infinite loop and you have that in all your versions

Comment: @TedLyngmo - unless its connected to real hardware - which seems possible in this case (SPI)

Comment: @pm100 Could be. I searched for `volatile` but didn't find any, but `SPI1STATbits` is probably global, so who knows. We'll have to make guesses since we don't see a [mre].

Comment: Pointers are not polymorphic in `c`, so in `SPI1BUF = *dt++`, `dt` must be of one specific type known at compile-time.

Comment: Serial data transfer is conducted with bytes. What is it you hope to achieve with this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil the code not compile in code 1, because "dt" variable scope inside switch-case is different from "dt" variable scope inside for loop.

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the bytes of a 8,16 or 32 byte value and send them one at a time to SPI?. But if so why change the SPI mode. Also how is SPI1BUF defined

Comment: The correct way to do this is with three functions, e.g. `void write_data_spi1_32(uint32_t *data_address, uint32_t size)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 this pic32 can transfer 8bit, 16bit and 32bit "words".

Comment: @TedLyngmo SPI1STATbits.SPITBF is a hardware flag (SPI Transmit Buffer Full Status bit).

Comment: @baldhead Thanks. I didn't know that.  In that case, seems it would be simpler to write 3 separate trivial functions than try to practice black magic in one generic function. The caller "knows" which of the 3 to use...

Comment: @pm100 I would like to create a generic function to send 8 bits or 16 bits or 32 bits. I can create 3 separate functions for this, one function for transfer 8 bits, another function for transfer 16 bits and another function to transfer 32 bits.

Comment: If you want a generic function, then you should look into the `_Generic` keyword. You still need to write the three functions, but you use a `_Generic` statement to select which function to call.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 3 separate functions using a macro:

```c
#define TFUNC(X)                                     \
    inline void funcdef_##X(X* dt, uint32_t size) {  \
        spi1_change_mode_##X();                      \
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {        \
            while (SPI1STATbits.SPITBF)              \
                ;                                    \
            SPI1BUF = *dt++;                         \
        }                                            \
    }

TFUNC(uint8_t)
TFUNC(uint16_t)
TFUNC(uint32_t)
```

Note: You'd have to rename `spi1_change_mode_8_bits` into `spi1_change_mode_uint8_t` etc. for the above to work.

Then use a `_Generic` as a front-end:

```c
#define write_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer_x_bits(X,S) \
             _Generic((X),                          \
                uint8_t* : funcdef_uint8_t,         \
               uint16_t* : funcdef_uint16_t,        \
               uint32_t* : funcdef_uint32_t)        \
             (X, S)
```

You'd then call it by a cast of `data_address` to the proper type and it'll select the correct function to call. Example:

```c
inline int32_t rite_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer(void* data_address, uint32_t size,
                                              bits_width data_type) {
    switch (data_type) {
    case bits_8:
        write_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer_x_bits((uint8_t*)data_address, size);
        break;
    case bits_16:
        write_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer_x_bits((uint16_t*)data_address, size);
        break;
    case bits_32:
        write_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer_x_bits((uint32_t*)data_address, size);
        break;
    default:
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `_Generic`, yet unless `void* data_address` is properly aligned, `(uint16_t*)data_address` and `uint32_t*)data_address` are UB.  Somewhat common (and fatal) in embedded world.  A better approach avoid that.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks and true! I can only hope that it really is aligned for `uint32_t`s.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like this C "generic" syntax.

I would simple:

1. Avoid pointer punning
2. Set the register in the `switch() ... case`

```
inline int32_t write_data_spi1_enhanced_buffer_x_bits( void* data_address, uint32_t size, bits_width data_type )
{       
    unsigned char *uda = data_address;
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;
    
    for( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {       
        while( SPI1STATbits.SPITBF );
            switch( data_type )
            {
            case bits_8:
                SPI1BUF = uda[i];
                break;

            case bits_16:
                memcpy(&u16, uda + sizeof(u16) * i, sizeof(u16));
                SPI1BUF = u16;
                break;

            case bits_32:            
                memcpy(&u32, uda + sizeof(u32) * i, sizeof(u32));
                SPI1BUF = u32;
                break;
            
            default:
                return -1;
            break;
            }    
    }
}
```

`memcpy` will be optimized out on targets not needing special alignment.